# python django: views, models and forms in directories

Tags: python, django

django 1.11

python 3.x

I have been trying to breakout models, views and forms into folders.  I started out with models and it seemed to work.  Changing `views.py` to `views/index.py` is stumping me.

I have seen posts on this and I *think* that I am setting the `__init__.py` files correctly but `makemigrations` still yells at me about `views/Profile.py`.

```
  File "/home/me/AppBase/MyApp/Members/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/me/AppBase/MyApp/Members/views/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Profile import *
  File "/home/me/AppBase/MyApp/Members/views/Profile.py", line 7, in <module>
    from MyApp.Members.models.Profile import *
ImportError: No module named 'MyApp.Members'
```

the file structure

```
MyApp
|-- Members
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- account_adapter.py
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- forms
|   |   |-- ProfileForm.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models
|   |   |-- Profile.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- views
|       |-- Profile.py
|       |-- __init__.py
```

`views/__init__.py` is:

```
    from .Profile import *
```

`views/Profile.py` is:

```
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.core.exceptions import *
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from django.shortcuts import render

    from MyApp.Members.models.Profile import *


    def create_profile(user):
        pass


    def profile(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/account/login')

        try:
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            messages.add_message(request, 1, "have profile")
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.add_message(request, 1, "create profile")
            create_profile(request.user)

        return render(request, 'Members/index.html')
```

`urls.py` is:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url

    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.Profile, name='profile'),
    ]
```

I am using PyCharm as the IDE and it claims all the paths are ok.  I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I think you are missing an `__init__.py` in the same level of Members folder

Comment: Sorry, it is there, I didn't include it to keep the post as small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Members.models.Profile import *
```

you dont need absolute import from the project name, use the appname and then import what you need, hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! That worked.  PyCharm claims that there is an unresolved reference to Members but I'll ignore that.